# Variable not showing on blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating a CRUD with 2 models in a form: automations and rules. 1 automation has 1 rule. On the edit form, I need to show field both from automations and rules.
This is my controller on edit method.

```
public function edit($id)
{

    $actions = array(
            1 => 'Enable',
            2 => 'Pause',
        );

    $fields = \DB::table('fields')
    ->whereNull('field1_id')
    ->lists('field_name', 'id');

    $schedules = \DB::table('schedules')
    ->lists('schedule_name', 'id');

    $rules = \DB::table('rules')
        ->where('automation_id', '=', $id)
        ->get();


    return view('automations.automations', [
        'automations' => Automations::find($id),
        'actions' => $actions,
        'fields' => $fields,
        'schedules' => $schedules,
        'rules' => $rules
    ]);
```

But on my form, I my not able to show the values from Rules, only for Automations. What I am doing wrong? This is the blade form for 1 field from Rules:

```
<div class="form-group">


    <label for="task-name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Field 1 </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {!! 

                    Form::select(   
                        'field1', 
                        (['' => 'Select a Field'] + $fields), 
                        (isset($rules->field1) ? $rules->field1 : null),  
                        ['class' => 'form-control','id' => 'field1']
                    ) 


                !!}
            </div>
            </div>
```

And for 1 field from automations:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="task-name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Action on Campaigns</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {!! 

                    Form::select(   
                        'action_id', 
                        (['' => 'Select an Action'] + $actions), 
                        (isset($automations->action_id) ? $automations->action_id : null),  
                        ['class' => 'form-control']
                    ) 


                !!}
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Make `dd($rules)` and check what is the output, also u are using `get()` call `$rules->isEmpty()` it will return if an object is empty or not just to check)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DB::get()` returns an array of stdClass objects. Therefore, `$rules` is an array, so you can't just access properties like `$rules->field1`. You need to iterate the array to find the actual object you're looking for, and then check that object. Or, if there's actually only one record, you can use `first()` instead of `get()`.

`DB::find()` returns `stdClass` object or null, depending on if the record was found. That is why your automations works.